# Tile Map Coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am have now this code: http://jsfiddle.net/DK67k/2/
In here is 2D tile map and when you click on tile you get coordinates on alert.
But for get precises coordinate you need click on top left tile(tiles is 16x16) and if I click on bottom right tile I am get second tile coordinates.

Maybe anyone have idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blaus' answer is correct.
Though you might want to subtract the canvas offset left- and top position to make your canvas element available for dynamic positioning, and not relative to the 10px padding.

```
function mouseCheck(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    mouseX = Math.floor(x / 16);
    mouseY = Math.floor(y / 16);
}
```

Comment: @hellozimi I should learn javascript. I'm intrigued about the lack of a loop for draw. I suppose that if you need to move something you will have to add a listener to a paint event or similar :?

Answer (score 3):

The canvas point (0,0) is at mouse coords (10,10), i think is due to parent of canvas has a padding area.

```
function mouseCheck(e) {
   x = e.pageX-10;
   y = e.pageY-10;
   mouseX = Math.floor(x / 16);
   mouseY = Math.floor(y / 16);
}
```